# Is there a "not_expects" for mocha/rspec?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, mocking, ruby-mocha

I need to make sure a method is not called giving a specific set of conditions, and I'm 
looking for the opposite of the mocha expects.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Look at mocha's [`never`](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#never-instance_method) or rspec's [`should_not_receive`](http://rspec.info/documentation/mocks/message_expectations.html) and `should_receive(:selector).exactly(n).times`

Comment: Mocha link is outdated. [New documentation on never](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#never-instance_method)

Answer (score 3):

I'm not a mocha expert by any means, but I suspect what you need may be supplied by a [never](http://mocha.rubyforge.org/classes/Mocha/Expectation.html#M000040) modifier for an expectation.

Answer (score 3):

Mocha example from the [documentation](http://gofreerange.com/mocha/docs/Mocha/Expectation.html#never-instance_method)

```
object = mock()
object.expects(:expected_method).never
object.expected_method # => unexpected invocation

object = mock()
object.expects(:expected_method).never
# => verify succeeds
```

Answer (score 2):

RSpec 3.6 now handles this with [expect(...).not_to receive(...)](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-mocks/docs/basics/expecting-messages#passing-negative-message-expectation).

From the link:

```
RSpec.describe "A negative message expectation" do
  it "passes if the message is never received" do
    dbl = double("Some Collaborator").as_null_object
    expect(dbl).not_to receive(:foo)
  end
end
```